# How to manipulate contents of a Django template based on value of radio button elements (without JS)

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

In a Django template, I have two radio buttons. If the second of these radio buttons is **selected**, I want certain follow-up elements to show. How do I do this in the Django template?

Here's my code:

```
<form method="post" action="" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
Privacy:<br>
{% for radio in form.private %}
    <table><tr><label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">
    <td><span>{{ radio.choice_label }}</span>
    <span class="radio">{{ radio.tag }}</span></td>
    </label></tr></table>
{% endfor %}<br>
{% if radio.tag == 'value1' %}  
    {{ form.rules.errors }}
    {{ form.rules.label_tag }}{{ form.rules }}<br>
{% endif %}
    <br>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Currently, I'm trying `{% if radio.tag == 'value1' %}` to try and accomplish what I posted in my question at the top, i.e., if the radio tag has a certain value, element called `rules` will display. Needless to say, it's not working for me. Any suggestions? I'd prefer **not to use Javascript**, because more than 80% of the users using this system have legacy phone devices that do not support JS.

*Note: please ask me for any clarifications, where warranted. I may not have successfully provided all the information you need.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare as follows:

```
{% if radio.choice_value == 'value1' %}
```

`radio.tag` is a method that returns the entire HTML of the input, which is why your comparison fails.

Comment: I suppose for this to work, I'll have to submit the form first, just 'selecting' a radio button won't work?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? `choice_value` is always defined, whether or not the form is bound.